# Kafka - Producer Number of Batches

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is there a way to determine the number of batches that were created by a Kafka producer for a specific set of messages? For instance if I am sending 10K messages in a loop , is there a way to check how many batches were sent? I set the "batch.size" to a high value and my expectation was that the message will be buffered and there will be a delay in seeing the message in my consumer. However this seems to be printed almost immediately in my consumer program.

The default value if batch.size is 16384. Is this number of bytes?

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;


public class KafkaProducerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094");
        properties.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("acks","0");
        properties.put("batch.size",33554432);

        KafkaProducer<String,String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
        Map<Integer,Integer> partitionCount = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        partitionCount.put(0,0);
        partitionCount.put(1,0);
        partitionCount.put(2,0);


        try{
            Date from = new Date();
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
                RecordMetadata ack = kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test_topic", Integer.toString(i), "MyMessage" + Integer.toString(i))).get();
                //RecordMetadata ack = kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String,String>("test_topic",0,Integer.toString(i), "MyMessage" + Integer.toString(i))).get();
                System.out.println(" Offset = " + ack.offset());
                System.out.println(" Partition = " + ack.partition());
                partitionCount.put(ack.partition(),partitionCount.get(ack.partition())+1);

            }
            Date to = new Date();
            System.out.println(" partition 0 =" + partitionCount.get(0));
            System.out.println(" partition 1 =" + partitionCount.get(1));
            System.out.println(" partition 2 =" + partitionCount.get(2));
            System.out.println(" Elapsed Time = " + (to.getTime()-from.getTime())/1000);

        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            kafkaProducer.close();
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is the total number of produce requests.

You can see the average number of produce requests per second using the JMX Mbean kafka.producer:type=producer-metrics,client-id=([-.w]+)

Comment: Thanks Hans! I set the "batch.size" to a high value and my expectation was that the message will be buffered and there will be a delay in seeing the message in my consumer. However this seems to be printed almost immediately in my consumer program. Wouldn't there be a delay? How can I determine if it is really being buffered?

Comment: Everything in Kafka is buffered. Both producer and consumer. There are both size and time based thresholds though so don't expect that it will only send a batch when the entire buffer is full. Take a look at the description about linger.ms and batch.size here http://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Comment: When I added linger of 1000 ms , I see that it takes about 30 seconds to send 100 messages to consumer. But when linger is set to default (1ms) , the messages are sent to consumer in less than 1 second. I thought all the messages will be buffered quickly and sent as a single message when linger time expires but doesn't seem to be the case.Can you please help explain this?

Comment: It will send what ever is in the buffer when the batch size is exceeded or the linger time has expired (whichever comes first). When you set linger.ms to 1 ms it is sending messages quickly but when you set it to 1000ms (1second) it's waiting longer between each produce request. I think the default linger.ms is 0 which means it sends the contents of the buffer immediately.

Comment: But I thought the purpose of buffer is to utilize the resources efficiently and perform dat transfer quickly. In the video that I saw there was an example where they mentioned it is like transferring data in a big truck in few attempts instead of transferring in a small car using multiple attempts which would take longer.

Comment: The buffer has several purposes. It's also there to allow an async send() with automatic retries in the case the broker is down or the network gets temporarily disconnected. If you want to use the buffer for better batching then set it to linger.ms = 5 or something that allows multiple messages to get batched together but doesn't slow everything down if your producer is not sending lists of messages.